# How long does it usually take for an online tournament to start?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, tournament

I registered for my first online tournament at FullTilt about half an hour ago. The tournament has the following structure:

4$ buy-in, 4 placed paid and starting when 18 people have registered.

There are currently 3 people (including me) registered. So my question is: how long does it usually take before such a tournament starts? And how do I know it started? Do I have to monitor it all the time? At this rate it would take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it, the tournament in question is a Sit'n'Go.

These types of tournaments don't have an official start time; they begin when the required number of players have registered (in your case: 18 players).

It might take 5 minutes or it might take 12 hours, there's no way to know. Usually, the smaller the buy-in and the higher the number of currently online players, the faster it will be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do I know if it has started? Do I have to stay at my computer until it starts?

Comment: @TmKVU You can register and then leave the poker client open. When the tournament starts, the table you're assigned at will automatically appear on your screen. Good luck.